# Delay layer output for one iteration

Tags: caffe, conv-neural-network

I have a fcn which should analyse a video. I want to use the output of the network as input for the net in the next iteration. Is there a layer which can do this? If not, is it possible to write such a layer in a reasonable amount of time? If so, do you have any advices I should consider while porgramming the layer?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are looking for a [`"Recurrent"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/recurrent.html) layer.
Note that having a recurrence in your net, the net now has a "cycle" in its underlying graph. Caffe usually uses "unrolling" to work around these cyclic graphs.

Comment: 1. Is there any tutorial for using a recurrent layer in this kind of network? Can I just say that the bottom of my first layer is the output of the "Recurrent" layer? Do I need to set some special parameters to achieve my goal? The only example I on recurrent networks in caffe I find are lstm layer which don't create cycles.

2. You mention that: "Caffe usually uses "unrolling" to work around these cyclic graphs." Is this a big problem? Can I work around this problem?

Comment: @SimpleNotGood lstm does create a loop: it does feed t+1 time step with responses compute at time t

Comment: All right, thank you. Last 2 question (and probably stupid ones): 1. can a LSTM layer get an input blob with a random shape (for example an image) and output the blob with the same shape? 2. Do batches still work in nets with a lstm layer? Batches are for training my net on multiple datas in parallel, but my net would have kind of a serial training structure. I guess this would make parallel training hard